# How to write in encrypted .xlsx file using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, encryption, overwrite

I try to overwrite in a existing encrypted file. Reading works fine but writing crashes at 
`"---cell.setCellValue("data");---"`. with Source not found.

```
public boolean excelWrite(String startLabel, String seitenLabel, String Pfad, double data, int zeile, int reihe)
    {
        try
        {

            NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File(Pfad));
            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
            Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
            try
            {

                if (!d.verifyPassword("XYZ"))
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process...");
                }
                InputStream dataStream = d.getDataStream(fs);
                XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(dataStream);
                try
                {

                    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(seitenLabel);
                    XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(zeile).getCell(reihe);

                    cell.setCellValue("data");
                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Pfad);
                    wb.write(out);
                    out.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            catch (GeneralSecurityException ex)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process...", ex);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: No idea why but it works now. The xlsx it not encrypted after that but you can encrypt it like shown on apache.org.

Comment: If you intend to eventually also write a password protected file, don't use POI 3.12 (beta,final, ...). I've introduced a bug into the encryption routines there, which calculates a wrong checksum. this has been fixed by 3.13 beta1